Representing logical expressions as an Object?
How can I represent logical expressions that might or might not contain brackets as a object in Java?
I want to be able to be able to evaluate expressions that can be from only A to A AND B or more complex like A AND (B OR (C AND D AND E))
I tried to represent as the following Object:
public class Condition {
    private boolean checked;
    private String operator; // AND, OR, or NESTED
    private List<Condition> nestedExpressions; // For nested expressions
}

And tried to use a list of Condition object, iterating recursively through this list, but if I set an operator NESTED, I can't add anything following it, because it doesn't work.
Is there a better way to represent a logical expression in java? Or is there any library that can help me with it?
public class Condition {
    private boolean checked;
    private String operator; // AND, OR
}

/\ this code works with simple, no brackets expressions, such as: A AND B OR C, but I want to handle more complex structures.

There are libraries out there like LogicNG. But if you want to go further with your Implementation i would represent it as a binary tree.

Have you searched for other questions about Boolean parsers?

Are you trying to parse the expression into an structure, evaluate the structure or both?

You don't need a NESTED operator. You just need to contain a condition that itself has its own NestedExpressions. So to take your complex example, you need A AND F where F is ``B OR G, and GisC AND D AND E`.

A parser reads the source code and generates something like a Abstract Syntax Tree which can then be executed (say by an interpreter) or used to generate machine or object code.

What btilly said. Your nodes have 2 flavours: class AtomicNode extends Node (a letter such as 'B'), and class OperatorNode extends Node (such as AND or OR). operators have 2 nodes that are their left and right hand side. These can, themselves, be either flavour of Node. You don't need parentheses, those are ways to disambiguate confusion caused by writing it down. Think about it. draw out (A AND B) OR C and A AND (B OR C) in trees. You'll find you don't need them. That, or, use a library like LogicNG.

It depends on what you want to do with those expressions?  You want to simplify them? You want to resolve the variables to true/false? Immediately or later?

Thank you all for the answers.
I was completely forgetting about the possibility to use a tree on this case, I guess I was already stuck on a train of thought and couldn't see further than it, so thank you so much for the suggestions and insights.. And I'll for sure look the LogicNG library as well.

It's a simple Boolean expression. Parse it with the Shunting Yard, and store the postfix output as a string in your object. It's simpler than a binary tree, and evaluating a postfix expression is really easy.

You could do something like
public interface Condition {
   boolean evaluate();
}

public class AndCondition implements Condition {
   private Condition left;
   private Condition right;

   // TODO constructor

   public boolean evaluate() {
      return left.evaluate() && right.evaluate();
   }

   public String toString() {
      return String.format("(%s) && (%s)", left, right);
   }
}

public class OrCondition implements Condition {
   private Condition left;
   private Condition right;

   // TODO constructor

   public boolean evaluate() {
      return left.evaluate() || right.evaluate();
   }

   public String toString() {
      return String.format("(%s) || (%s)", left, right);
   }
}

public class NotCondition implements Condition {
   private Condition condition;

   // TODO constructor

   public boolean evaluate() {
      return !condition.evaluate();
   }

   public String toString() {
      return String.format("!(%s)", condition);
   }
}

Then
public static void main() {

   Condition a = () -> true;
   Condition b = () -> false;
   Condition c = () -> false;

   Condition aAndB = new AndCondition(a, b);
   Condition aOrB = new OrCondition(a, b);
   Condition aAndBOrC = new OrCondition(aAndB, c);
   Condition notA = new NotCondition(a);

   System.out.println("a && b = " + aAndB.evaluate());
   System.out.println("a || b = " + aOrB.evaluate());
   System.out.println("(a && b) || c = " + aAndBOrC.evaluate());
   System.out.println("!a = " + notA.evaluate());
}


Often, conditions would be defined by a Condition interface with methods for things you want to be able to do with a condition, like evaluate it.  Then you have subclasses that implement different operators.
Modeling conditions as data is a little awkward in Java, but conditions are simple enough that you can make it work.  If I had to do it, I might try something like this:
enum ConditionOperator { AND, OR };

public class Condition {
    public ConditionOperator operator;
    public List<Condition> conditions;
    public List<String> trueLiterals;
    public List<String> falseLiterals;
}

This can represent any condition as the AND or OR of subconditions and literals.
Some notes on this representation:

AND with no children is always TRUE
OR with no children is always FALSE
If there's exactly one child, then the operator is not relevant
There is no NOT operator, because it isn't necessary.  To negate
literals, you just move them between the trueLiterals and falseLiterals. lists.  To negate a whole condition, apply De Morgan's threorem

You can think of a Condition as a set of parentheses, and the fields  say what's between those parentheses.

Note the downvote.  The other answer is the idiomatic Java way...  But it requires the definition of the Condition interface to anticipate all the things you want to do with conditions, probably forcing an annoying visitor pattern implementation of anything that wasn't specifically anticipated.  That's what makes it different from a "conditions as data" solution like this one.  Languages like Typescript are more convenient for these kinds of cases.
